# How to make a text box accept only numbers in celltemplate ng-grid?

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid

I am declaring a text box inside ng-grid using celltemplate. Is there a way to make this textbox accept only numeric values? Here is my cell template:

```
'<div class="ngCellText"><div ng-show="!row.entity.col3">{{row.getProperty(col.field)}}</div>' +
            '<div ng-show="row.entity.col3" class="ngCellText"><input style="background-color:{{colorCell}}" ng-change="colorchange(this,row.entity.col2)"  type="text"  ng-model="row.entity.col2" /></div></div>'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily create a pattern inside your input text box like this and check for  validation.

```
   '<form name="myForm"><div class="ngCellText"><div ng-show="!row.entity.col3">{{row.getProperty(col.field)}}</div>' +
                '<div ng-show="row.entity.col3" class="ngCellText"><input style="background-color:{{colorCell}}" ng- change="colorchange(this,row.entity.col2)" ng-pattern="/^(\d)+$/" name="color" type="text"  ng-model="row.entity.col2" /></div></div> <span class="error pop_up  "
                      ng-show="myForm.color.$error.pattern">Please enter only number</span></form>'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set grid options as below.

```
$scope.gridOptions = {
          columnDefs: [
              {field: 'Jan', displayName: 'January', enableColumnMenu: false, type: 'number' }];
          };
```

i hope this answer is helpful..

Comment: number type not working its allow the user to add characters also any other prop we can set for allowing number only?